# Deploy custom Angular 6 app to Cumulocity Tenant

Tags: cumulocity

We are trying to create a custom app using Angular 6. We managed to deploy an Angular 2 app using this ( https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angular2 ) example, adding the cumulocity.json file and zipping it.

With Angular 6 we are using Angular CLI to create a project, and used "ng build" to build the app but when we zip the content of the dist folder, even when adding cumulocity.json to it, we only get a blank page when deploying it to the tenant (it's working with "ng serve" on my computer). Any hints how we should proceed or what we are missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you use routing for it? If yes pls see [this Github issue](https://github.com/dwiyatci/c8y-angular-polymer-boilerplate/issues/1#issuecomment-412891427). Maybe that answers your question?

Answer (score -2):

Kindly check this link, maybe this is your answer[CLick](https://tech.forums.softwareag.com/t/cumulocity-custom-angular-application-development/237547)

When you build your angular app after checking the doc.
After that, you are going to make the zip.
Before making zip open index.html inside your build folder and add a "/" on-base href.
[CLICK IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1x3Q.png)
your href shd look like this

Comment: What is in that link? Why should we check it out?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To deploy and build angular app you can check the link

Comment: A good answer should not depend on external links. Please quote the relevant material from the link in your answer.